# How to read a list of values from column in a datatable which has a data from a xml file to a combo box in datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have the following xml file

```
<WG>
  <WGT>
  <TName>tanme1</TName> 
  <Fname>fname1</Fname> 
  <Product>Product1</Product> 
  <Product>Product2 </Product> 
  </WGT>
  <WGT>
  <TName>tanme2</TName> 
  <Fname>fname2</Fname> 
  </WGT>
  <WGT>
  <TName>tanme1</TName> 
  <Fname>fname1</Fname> 
  <Product>Product1</Product> 
  <Product>Product2 </Product> 
  <Product>Product3 </Product> 
  <Product>Product4 </Product> 
  </WGT>
</WG>
```

I'm trying to bind it to datagrid in View(xaml code)

Below is the code snippet in ViewModel class.

```
private DataTable dt;
public DataTable DT
       {

           get
           {
               return dt;


           }
           set
           {
               dt = value;
               NotifyPropertyChanged("DT");
           }
       }

XmlReader xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("C:/Wafers/WGen.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
dt = ds.Tables[0];
```

When running a wpf project, in view I can see only "TName' and "Fname" field and values.

I would like to display list of product values in a combo box in the datagrid through binding.
How to retrieve all the product values to a list from data table dt in viewmodel class so that I can bind it in view?

Comment: Mong Zhu, I have already checked it . It's not working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Create a DataGridTemplateColumn:

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Product" Width="Auto" MinWidth="120">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate DataType="YourModel">
                        <ComboBox
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Products}"                                
                            SelectedValuePath="Key" 
                            DisplayMemberPath="Key"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"

                            />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The ItemSource isa dictionary with your model products keys and values.

Add:

```
 Dictionary<string, string> Products{ get; set; }
```

To your model and fill each model with it's products.

Comment: How to retrieve values to Products from data table? How to use LINQ query?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this method, In dt you can get product values

Property

```
 private DataView dt;
        public DataView DT
        {

            get
            {
                return dt;
            }
            set
            {
                dt = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("DT");
            }
        }
```

ViewModel:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("d:\\file.txt");
            XmlReader xmlFile = new XmlNodeReader(doc);

           DataSet ds = new DataSet();
           ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
           DT = ds.Tables[1].AsDataView();
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbBox" ItemsSource="{Binding DT}" Width="100" Height="100" DisplayMemberPath="Product_Text" SelectedValuePath="WGT_Id"></ComboBox>
```

Comment: Justin CI, thanks for the reply. I have tried the same way earlier, the thing is TName and Fname is displaying fine in datagrid but product values are not populating in combo box inside datagrid cell template.

Comment: can someone validate this statement? Does this pull all the product values? List<string> ids = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("Product")).ToList();

Comment: @ganeshshsf you are using ds.Tables[0] change it to ds.Tables[1]

Comment: if I change ds.Tables[0] to ds.Tables[1] , other 2 fields are not appearing, namely TName and Fname in datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom DataGrid from the dataTable:

1.Xaml:

```
   <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding GenericDataView}"
                      attachedBehaviors:DataGridColumnsBehavior.BindableColumns="{Binding GridColumns}"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      EnableRowVirtualization="False"
                      />
```

2.Fill your dataTable
3.Create GridColumnsCollection and DataView:

```
 GridColumns = new ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>();
  public DataView GenericDataView { get; private set; }
```

4.Go through your dataTable rows and create your cusom column, here is example of ComboBoxColumn created dynamically:

```
        ItemsProducts = new ObservableCollection<productModel>();
                                        ItemsProducts = YourProducts           
                                        DataGridComboBoxColumn comboBoxColumn = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
                                        comboBoxColumn.Header = row["displayname"].ToString();
                                        comboBoxColumn.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
                                        comboBoxColumn.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
                                        Binding binding = new Binding();
                                        binding.Path = new PropertyPath(row["name"].ToString());
                                        comboBoxColumn.SelectedValueBinding = binding;
                                        Binding itemsSourceBinding = new Binding();
                                        itemsSourceBinding.Source = ItemsProducts;
                                        BindingOperations.SetBinding(comboBoxColumn, DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSourceProperty, itemsSourceBinding);

                                        GridColumns.Add(comboBoxColumn);
                                    }
                                    ColumnsList.Add(row["name"].ToString()); //add the real column name
```

5.After looping all the rows and filling the data:

```
    RaisePropertyChanged("GridColumns");
    GenericDataView = new DataView(dt);
    RaisePropertyChanged("GenericDataView");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I do not know how to get "product values " from xml file to assign it to the below statement. ItemsProducts = YourProducts

Comment: Use Linq:  var WGTS =      XDocument.Load(XmlFilePath).Descendants("WGT");
            foreach (XElement xElement in WGTS)
            {
                foreach (var p in xElement.Elements("Product"))
                {
                    
                }
            }